# How to make an ng-if with a directive scope defined with @?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried this:

```
'<td ng-if="{{listName == groups}}"><a ng-href="#/groups/{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</a></td>',
scope: {
listName: "@"
```

And this tag is still not showing. Am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: share JS fiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
ng-if="{{listName == groups}}"
```

Try this

```
ng-if="listName == groups"
```